# C++ operator >> overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a customer class as following,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "SimpleDate.h"

using namespace std;

class Customer {

private:
    string customerId;
    string name;
    string address;
    string city;
    string postCode;
    SimpleDate* dateLastPurchased;
    double dollarsOwed;

public:
    //Customer(string customerIdVal, string nameVal);
    Customer();
    string getCustomerId();
    string getName();
    void setAddress(string addressVal);
    string getAddress();
    void setPostCode(string postCodeVal);
    string getPostCode();
    void setCity(string cityVal);
    string getCity();
    void setDateLastPurchased(SimpleDate* date);
    SimpleDate* getDateLastPurchased();
    void addDollarsOwed(double amount);
    double getDollarsOwed();

    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, Customer &cust);
    friend istream& operator>> (istream &in, Customer &cust);
};
```

Overloading sections in the cpp file looks as following

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, Customer &cust)
{
    out << cust.customerId << "\t" << cust.name << "\t" << cust.address << "\t" << cust.city << "\t" << cust.postCode << "\t" << cust.dateLastPurchased->getFullDate() << "\t" << cust.dollarsOwed << "\t" << std::endl;
    return out;
}

istream& operator>> (istream &in, Customer &cust)
{
    in >> cust.customerId;
    in >> cust.name;
    in >> cust.address;
    in >> cust.city;
    in >> cust.postCode;

    string stringData;
    in >> stringData;

    std::istringstream iss(stringData);
    std::string datePart;
    int tmp;
    vector<int> dateData;

    while(std::getline(iss, datePart, '/')) {

        sscanf(datePart.c_str(), "%d", &tmp);       
        dateData.push_back(tmp);
    }

    SimpleDate* date = new SimpleDate(dateData[2], dateData[1], dateData[0]);
    cust.dateLastPurchased = date;

    string stringDollarsOwed;
    in >> stringDollarsOwed;

    sscanf(stringDollarsOwed.c_str(), "%lf", &cust.dollarsOwed);

    return in;
}
```

Then in my main class I try to create a customer object as following,

```
Customer* cust = new Customer();

    cust << customerInfo[0] << customerInfo[1] << customerInfo[2] << customerInfo[3] << customerInfo[4] << customerInfo[5] << customerInfo[6];
```

But when I'm compiling I get the following error,

can you please help?

Thanks.

```
AppManager.cpp: In member function 'Customer* AppManager::createCustomerObject(std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >)':
AppManager.cpp:445: error: no match for 'operator<<' in '& cust << customerInfo.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[] [with _Tp = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >](0u)'
Customer.h:46: note: candidates are: std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Customer&)
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `Tour'
```

Comment: You've shown `operator>>`, but the error message is about `operator<<`. You've defined `ostream &operator<<(ostream &, Customer &)`. You normally want `Customer const &` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be inserting the customerInfo[0] etc objects into the cust object that you have created. You cannot insert one object into another like that. The insertion/extraction operator as they are overloaded can only be used with as they are with primitive datatypes, i.e. storing and displaying values in the objects.

Comment: I'm trying to set the properties of the customer, customerInfo[0] is a string value

Comment: If you want to read the values from the string into the object then you need to write a separate function, that can parse the string (may be your string is ',', '-', '_' etc delimited)and populate the fields of the object.

Comment: I have a function that already does that :) customerInfo is a vector of string values, I'm trying to set them in the object using >>.

Answer (score 1):

This operator:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, Customer &cust)
```

allows you do do things like

```
Customer c;
std::cout << c << std::endl;
std::ofstream output("customers.txt");
output << c << std::endl;
```

and **not**

```
Customer c;
c << x;
```

and definitely not

```
Customer* c = ...;
c << x;
```

Comment: I'm trying to set the properties of the customer, customerInfo[0] is a string value